# an algorithm to check the strength of the password in c/c++

Tags: c, passwords

I tried to make an algorithm to check if a string has upper, lower and a digit in it, and if it has it should print "strong password", if not "weak password". but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
int main() 
{
    int i = 0;
    char string1[100];

    printf("Please enter password\n");
    gets(string1);

    if(strlen(stirng1) < 6)
    {
        printf("Password is too short\n");
    }
    if(islower(string1[i]) && isupper(string1[i]) && isdigit(string1[i]))
    {
        printf("Strong Password\n");
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("Weak Password\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: (apart from "stirng1" being misspelled)

Comment: This doesn't look like C#.

Comment: You need some loop in there to make it work...

Comment: try to use Regex match, it is faster and powerful

Comment: The difficulty of cracking a password lies in the storage of the password and in the set of valid passwords. It also depends on the kind of attack: brute force/dictionary/hash weaknesses/... You can't just say that "abcd" is a weak password. It is the strongest password amongst all passwords containing at most 4 characters and lower characters only.

Comment: This also isnt C#.. but C/C++..

Comment: @user1969786: Just fyi: you should never write "but it doesn't seem to be working." in your question. Alternatively include and example with expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool hasUpper = false;
bool hasLower = false;
bool hasDigit = false;

for(int i =0; i < strlen(string1); ++i)
{

    if( islower(string1[i]) )
        hasLower = true;

    if( isupper(string1[i]) )
        hasUpper = true;

    if( isdigit(string1[i]) )
        hasDigit = true;
}
if(hasLower && hasUpper && hasDigit)
{
    printf("Strong Password\n");
}
else
{ 
    printf("Weak Password\n");
}
```

Please note that while it's good to warn users about weak or short passwords, you should NEVER make it a requirement. By ruling out too many passwords, you actually make it easier for the attacker to brute force, because he can skip that. Also the password too hard to remember is unsafe, as user will be forced to write it down and postit to the monitor. Another thing is to make sure you can handle all characters properly, like space, tab, `"` or `/`. If user wants `" DROP TABLE 'users';` it's your job to handle it correctly.

Password strength is user's responsibility, because only the user knows if he's going to keep anything valuable in your system.

Comment: Could improve the for loop a bit, at the moment if it finds a lower character, it'll still check the other two. Also, once it finds all three, it doesn't really need to check the rest of the password.

Comment: @HaemEternal You're absolutely right, but it isn't really necessary to give the OP the idea on how to correctly implement it.

Comment: @HaemEternal Could, but since OP lacks grasp of basic concepts of C I wanted to highlight those instead of making the code more complicated. Such optimization would yield unnoticeable results, as passwords are quite short strings and `isSomething` functions are fast.

Answer (score 1):

The if-statement

```
if(islower(string1[i]) && isupper(string1[i]) && isdigit(string1[i]))
{
    printf("Strong Password\n");
}
```

will never be true, since `i` is 0 (still from initialization) and the first character of `string1` can't be lower case *and* upper case *and* a digit. You probably want a loop, checking if there is at least one upper case letter, one lower case and a digit in the password. See `Agent_L`s answer for how to do that (he posted while I was typing this, thanks ;-)).